# Select subscriptions based on user email

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I have these MySQL tables where I want to store user subscriptions:

```
CREATE TABLE subscription (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `amount` decimal(19,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` datetime(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `currency` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `duration` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `end_at` datetime(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `error` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `order_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `product` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `run_at` datetime(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `start_at` datetime(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `status` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` datetime(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `title` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `parent_transaction_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `parent_transactionId` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=23443556 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;


INSERT INTO subscription (`id`, `amount`, `created_at`, `currency`, `duration`, `end_at`, `error`, `order_id`, `product`, `run_at`, `start_at`, `status`, `updated_at`, `title`, `parent_transaction_id`, `parent_transactionId`) VALUES 
('122', '3333.00', '2020-10-31 19:41:16.622386', 'USD', '1000', '2020-10-31 19:41:16.622386', 'error message', '122', 'error message', '2020-10-31 19:41:16.622386', '2020-10-31 19:41:16.622386', 'active', '2020-10-31 19:41:16.622386', 'title', '443', '5544');

CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `email` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `enabled` tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `encrypted_password` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `first_name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `role` varchar(25) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=153 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `users` (`id`, `email`, `enabled`, `encrypted_password`, `first_name`, `last_name`, `role`) VALUES 
('192', 'test@mail.com', '1', '$2a$31$ovShEKleI3Yk2vgjAIF5mO4HkGWXcTSKPMTaj7rFN4KAtlEz0f/ay', 'test', 'test', 'ROLE_CLIENT');

CREATE TABLE `orders` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `city` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CONTENT` text DEFAULT NULL,
  `country` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` datetime(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `discount` decimal(8,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `email` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `first_name` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `grand_total` decimal(8,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `item_discount` decimal(8,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_name` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `line1` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `line2` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `middle_name` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `mobile` varchar(15) DEFAULT NULL,
  `promo` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `province` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `session_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `shipping` decimal(8,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `status` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sub_total` decimal(8,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `tax` decimal(8,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `token` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `total` decimal(8,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` datetime(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `user_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `phone` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=65 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `orders` (`id`, `city`, `CONTENT`, `country`, `created_at`, `email`, `first_name`, `grand_total`, `item_discount`, `last_name`, `status`, `sub_total`, `tax`, `total`, `user_id`) VALUES 
('122', 'city', 'test context', 'USA', '2021-05-25 12:40:23.793779', 'test@email.com', 'first name', '100', '10', 'last name', 'active', '20', '10', '200', '192');
INSERT INTO `orders` (`id`, `city`, `CONTENT`, `country`, `created_at`, `email`, `first_name`, `grand_total`, `item_discount`, `last_name`, `status`, `sub_total`, `tax`, `total`, `user_id`) VALUES 
('124', 'city', 'test context', 'USA', '2021-05-25 12:40:23.793779', 'test@email.com', 'first name', '100', '10', 'last name', 'active', '20', '10', '200', '192');


CREATE TABLE `order_item` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `discount` decimal(19,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `order_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `price` decimal(19,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `product_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `quantity` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sku` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1d6ba6/34

I use this SQL query with 2 JOINS to get the subsriptions:

```
SELECT *
FROM subscription s
INNER JOIN Orders o  ON s.order_id = o.id AND s.id = 122
INNER JOIN users u ON u.id = o.user_id
ORDER BY s.`created_at` 
LIMIT 1;
```

As you can see I use param id in order to make 2 JOINS. Is it possible just to send the user email from the table users as a param and get the subscription records that are found?

Comment: You have an `email` field in the `orders` table, so you could use that. But you shouldn't have redundant data like that in the first place. If the user changes their email, you'll have to update all their orders.

Comment: This is the issue. I want to use the `email` field from table `Users`.

Comment: So what's the problem? Add `WHERE u.email = 'user@domain.com'` to your query.

Comment: Is this possible to edit the query in a way so that I can use it here: `ON s.order_id = o.id AND s.id = 122`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conditions on single tables should go in the `WHERE` clause, not `ON`.

```
SELECT *
FROM subscription s
INNER JOIN Orders o  ON s.order_id = o.id
INNER JOIN users u ON u.id = o.user_id
WHERE u.email = 'user@example.com'
ORDER BY s.`created_at` 
LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: I can remove `s.id = 122` right? I don't need search by id.